# Compare difference between groups in time series data (what tests to use)?

Tags: r, time-series, mixed-model, anova, repeated-measures

I've got data tracking activity levels (how much movement) in mice as a proxy for measuring their sleep. I have a data point every minute over a number of days. There are two treatment groups and male / female.

I want to know how the treatment is affecting their overall activity and if it is reducing their amount of sleep during the light period (they are nocturnal). Also, if there are sex differences.

What statistical tests should I use? I ran a multiple ANOVA comparing mean activity levels in the light and dark period across all groups but as I've got so many observations the DFd (degrees of freedom denominator ?) was around 100000 which I'm guessing will make almost anything significant? I also have thought of using the hourly average activity over 24h rather than light/dark.

Does it matter that there are repeated measures for each mouse over time meaning that the hours are not truly independent? Also, you cant do less than 0 activity, so there are a lot of zeros and its not a nice two-tailed normal distribution shape.

Any advice of what statistical tests I should do would be greatly appreciated, preferably something doable in R. I've plotted smoothed out (rolling average) graphs of the activity over time between groups and mean difference box plots already.

Comment: How do you define "overall activity" ? Are you thinking about average movement or something else ? Can you make your research question(s) a bit more precise in terms of the data you have ?